# How to save giant JSON inside javascript with C++

Tags: javascript, c++, json, node.js

I have javascript code that is writing a giant hierarchic tree into a javascript object. The RAM is not the problem, even with --max_old_space_size set to 128 GB it still crashes. So I want to find a way to write this object to the disc with C++ inside javascript, or export the variable somehow to save it with C++ inside another program.

```js
db._txn({
    collections: {
        read:['rank_extract']
    }}, convert, (status, headers, body) => {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        fs.writeFileSync('treeee.json', JSON.stringify(body.result, false, 2));
        console.log("Finished tagging weinstein parasites/freeliving on full tree");
    });
```

I didn't find anything that suits my question. I have little to no experience in C++.

Comment: Why do you think using C++ would be a solution here? And what are you using to run this Javascript? Node? Please tag the environment. There may be a way to handle this without any C++ code. Why do you need to convert JSON back and forth? For formatting? Please describe the *actual* problem since this looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Sorry for being so unprecise at the first place. So the thing is: I get this huge tree back from a transactions which I run on a database. Maybe I could write it in some kind of controlled stream but I think the stringify is the problem.